# Is it possible to avoid PackageInstaller confirmation on Android 11?

Tags: android

I have an installer app for Android that uses PackageInstaller API (it's a regular app, declaring REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission). When the app installs an APK, Android returns backs STATUS_PENDING_USER_ACTION with the intent to run to request user confirmation. However, it also does that for every single app install/update. Android 12 introduced API like [PackageInstaller.SessionParams.setRequireUserAction](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.SessionParams#setRequireUserAction(int)), but I cannot find anything equivalent for Android 11. So the question is: is it at all possible to avoid user confirmation on Android 11?